# how to send ArrayList from sevrlet to jsp and print it

Tags: jsp, servlets

here i'm  setting data at students 
 i want to print value from Arraylist to jsp page

this is servlet class

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        studentDao =new StudentDao();
        List<Student> studentList=studentDao.display();

        request.setAttribute("students",studentList);
          for(Student stu:studentList){
            System.out.println(stu.getAge()+" " +stu.getStudentName());
        }
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/viewstudent.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(request,response);
    }//method end
```

//this is jsp page

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>view Student</title>
</head>
<body>
<table >
<c:forEach items="${students}" var="student">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${student.roll_no}"></c:out></td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code should works fine for Arraylist print in jsp, Please clarify your questions?

Answer (score -1):

`getRequestDispatcher("/viewstudent.jsp?students="+studentList);`

And on jsp just accept the value from the get method, e.g

`List<Student> studentList = (List<Student>)request.getParameter("students")`

Print it out like this;

`<%for(int i = 0; i<student.size();i++){ out.print(sutudent.getName());
}`

Just like that. The main point is passing the arrayList into the parameter of the link.

Comment: give compilation time error  
Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'java.lang.String' to 'java.util.List<com.dz.model.Student>'